After the third line, the Vue file inside the pages folder code is not covered
After the third line, the code in the pages folder was not covered when selecting the v8 for coverage. How can I achieve this? I have provided the configuration and code changes in below.
Vitest.config.mts
import { defineVitestConfig } from '@nuxt/test-utils/config'

export default defineVitestConfig({
  test: {
    environment: 'nuxt',
    environmentOptions: {
      nuxt: {
        domEnvironment: 'jsdom'
      }
    },
    silent: false,
    coverage: {
      enabled: true,
      provider: 'v8',
      reporter: ['html', 'text'],
      reportOnFailure: true,
      cleanOnRerun: true,
      reportsDirectory: './cireports/coverage',
      all: true,
      include: ['pages/**', 'components/**']
    }
  }
})

Package.json
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "test": "vitest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns": "*",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-grids": "^26.2.10",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-inputs": "^26.2.10",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-navigations": "*",
    "@testing-library/vue": "^8.1.0",
    "vue": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/test-utils": "3.14.4",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "2.1.4",
    "@vue/test-utils": "2.4.6",
    "jsdom": "25.0.1",
    "nuxt": "3.13.2",
    "vitest": "2.1.4"
  }
}

pages/index.vue
<template>
    <div v-if="a" id="page-header">
      <p class="page-title">hello</p>
      <p class="page-description">hii</p>
    </div>
    <div v-else id="page-header">
      <p class="page-title">hello</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
let a = false;
const message = 'Welcome to the page!';
console.log(message);

onMounted(() => {
  a=true
  console.log('Component mounted!'); 
});

</script>
<style>
.page-title {
  color: red;
}
</style>

spec/pages.spec.ts
import { describe, it, vi, beforeAll, afterAll } from 'vitest';
import { mountSuspended } from '@nuxt/test-utils/runtime';
import page from '../pages/index.vue';

describe('Test case to ensure grid component mount case', async () => {
    let pageWrapper: any;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        pageWrapper = await mountSuspended(page);   
        console.log('done');
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        vi.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('Test case to ensure the page component mount case', async () => {
        console.log(pageWrapper.html());
    })
});

Code not covered output

I have tried to change the path for pages in configuration, then I have created the separate file in the component folder, then I have mocked the file; it was covered, but in the pages folder it is not covering using v8, then I have changed the package "@vitest/coverage-v8" to "@vitest/coverage-istanbul," then I run the coverage it was covering, but how can I cover the pages folder using v8??

Is it maybe because it knows that a will always be true, hence skips the rest?

When the condition is not applied also it cover only first three lines in pages folder.
